# Appropriate to use this site to clarify doubts as a layman?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to hunt for some information on certain laws in India and started drowning in pdfs through link chasing and badly maintained websites. Is it appropriate for me to use this community to clarify any doubts I have about laws, which as a layman it is hard for me to understand directly?

Answer (score 7):

I would add that it's important to identify a matter where it is reasonable to expect there to be a law on the topic, and to be specific about the jurisdiction (there are both federal and state laws in India). Being specific is very desirable: a question like "Is misbehavior illegal" is unanswerable, because murder and farting are both forms of misbehavior. The ["marrying under 17" question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14689/can-the-police-arrest-me-for-marrying-an-underage-17-year-old-girl) is an example of a clear and answerable question. The ["Nazi symbol" question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11900/is-using-nazi-symbol-in-india-offensive) literally asks a legally unanswerable question (about being socially offensive) but it can be answered as if the question were "is it legal" (especially since the question is actually two questions, an irrelevant social one and a relevant legal one). Please ask one question; do not list many questions. Instead, ask a question, then later ask a different question.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, yes.  A request for legal information, or clarification regarding what the law says, is on-topic.

And as with all Stack Exchanges, it is usually beneficial for you to "show your work" after you frame your question.